# How would I change a certain field of a document every 3 hours with Firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I’m making an app that requires every 3 hours to update a certain field of a document. How would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for something called "Cron Job".

**The Idea behind it:** You create an HTTP triggered method in Firebase Functions, and assign an outer service (for example: Google App Engine) that is responsible to send the HTTP request routinely.

There isn't any Firebase-built-in solution, but you could use Google App Engine / other Cloud utility available out there.

Here's an [Excellent article](https://medium.com/@earlg3/google-cloud-functions-scheduled-trigger-915b5fb8310f) for implementing one with Firebase Functions.

[This one](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/03/how-to-schedule-cron-jobs-with-cloud.html) might help as well (Firebase Blog).

Comment: first link seems to not work